# How to increase the size of dots in the "dotted" line type without increasing the space between dots?

Tags: r

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/line-types-in-r-lty

`cex` seems to change both the size of the dots and the space between the dots. How to just change the dot size without changing the space between the dots?